# Changing textview on edittext ( when possible without a button)

Tags: java, android

I'm kinda new to java programming for android, so if i make stupid mistakes, i'm sorry.

So basically, what i wanna make is an app where if you type in the answer correctly, the next textview is gonna be displayed. And when the next textView is displayed, you're needing to give a answer to that textView, when the answer is given correctly. The textview changes again. And so on.

Does anybody have an idea how to do this?

If you don't undarstand what im saying, here is a example:

```
public class Game extends AppCompatActivity {
public static EditText editText_ans;
public static TextView textView_1;

String enteredText = editText.getText().toString();

    If(enteredText = 3 && textView_1 = @string/1+2){
setText.textView_1(@string/3+4)
 }
If(enteredText = 7 && textView_1 = @string/3+4){
setText.textView_1("100 - 23")
```

I'm really stuck and i hope that you guys wanna help me.

Comment: mean one question with answer if user type answer correctly it move to next question

Comment: Yes, I really dont't know how to do that! @YounasBangash

Comment: did you got solution or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int x=0; //to keep track of qustions
private List<String> mQuestionList=new ArrayList<>(); //array of question
private List<String> mAnswerList=new ArrayList<>(); //array of question answer
 displayquestion.settext(mQuestionList.get(x);//displayquestion is textview

 //nextquestion is the button when user click it will first check answer and than move to next question if answer is correct


    nextquestion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String answer=editText.getText().toString();
            if(answer.equal(mAnswerList.get(x)){
                x=x+1;
               displayquestion.settext(mQuestionList.get(x); //answer is correct display next quesion
            }else{
              //wrong answer
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to change the view without button you can use method addTextChangeListner() which will notify you when when the text hasbeen change for particular edittext.

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);


    private final TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.length() == 0) {
                textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else{
                textView.setText("You have entered : " + editText.getText());
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: I'd change `editText.getText()` to `s.toString()`, because I like being explicit about my `toString()` calls. Otherwise, good answer.

Comment: if it help you accept answer so that it help other user